# I am trying to name a column in my code as 'MA+_Apps'

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to name a column as 'MA+_Apps'. Getting an error everytime.

```
   Select date,SUM(ma_at_apps+mrsnp_at_apps) AS (ma +_at_apps)
```

from .....

Comment: I believe you might be able to do this by [wrapping your column name in double quotation marks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_names.html), but it would be much better to just get rid of the `+` in the column name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use delimited identifiers (double quotes)

`"MA+_Apps"` would work instead of `'MA+_Apps'`

But I believe it would be better to remove `+`, and if you really need to use it for some reason, you can substitute it like this `'MA_Plus_Apps'`